# Calling a method inside the class from a method list

Tags: vb.net, methods

ok I do have a class like this

```
Public NotInheritable Class Helper

  Private Function A(a As String) as Boolean
      Return True
  End Function

  Private Function B(a As String) as Boolean
      Return True
  End Function

End Class
```

Now as I want to call it by string name I want to **get the list of the methods inside of my instantiated object of the class**(If it can be returned as an array that is fine)

```
Dim h as New Helper()
'So it will list something like this
'[0] - A
'[1] - B
```

and I want to acquire the name of the 2nd method(which is method **B**) and call it using its name

```
 Dim methodObj As MethodInfo
 methodObj = Type.GetType("Common.Validation.Helper").GetMethod(ReturnAFunction(1))
 methodObj.Invoke(New Helper(), params))
```

is this possible? If not how can I make something closer on what I want? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the instance `h`  :

```
Dim h as New Helper()
```

you can use [`GetMethods()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx):

```
Dim yourPrivateMethods = h.GetType() _
                          .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance) _
                          .Where(Function(m) Not m.IsHideBySig) _
                          .ToArray() '' array contains A and B

'' get the method named 'B' and call it       
yourPrivateMethods.Single(Function(m) m.Name = "B").Invoke(h, {"the parameter"})
```

or simply [`GetMethod(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9.aspx):

```
h.GetType().GetMethod("B", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(h, {"the parameter"})
```

Note that, since your methods are private, you have to use the appropriate [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

Comment: it returns an error `Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Char'.` pointing to 'h' variable using the 2nd way you have said because I am using private methods

Comment: @Mahan Neither do I use `Char` anywhere in my code, nor does the code in your question use `Char` anywhere. So, obviously you try pass an argument of type `String` to a method that has a parameter of type `Char` in your *real* code. maybe you're looking for something like `.Invoke(h, {"X"c}`? Do you know the difference between `String` and  `Char`?

Comment: @Mahan If you have a specific problem, make a short example that reproduces it, maybe using [ideone](http://ideone.com/rPLH7i).

Comment: Ok I got it working but how can I get the return value of the function from being invoked?

Comment: Calling `.Invoke(...)` returns the return value of the function invoked. See [this](http://ideone.com/rPLH7i) example.